# Facebook Like button - comment box with breif description and image

Tags: facebook-like

On my website when  the user selects the facebook like button they have the option to enter comments. This popup window to enter comments only contains the users avatar and place to enter comments. How can i include my pic and a brief description of the site directly below the comment??? 
At first I thought it was from the HTML title attribute  or meta property="og:title" ... but populating these have no affect

I have another site that contains both pic and a desc below the comment but the pic seems to be grabed at random -but always the same- from the site and the short desc I thought from the -title- attribute but its not - I changed the -title- and it still shows the same desc, its like its cached???

Any ideas how to control or populate a brief description and image within the comment section of a like button???